# Concurrent.futures returns the same result every time

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, python-multithreading

I am trying to load multiple pages at the same time with `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

The code is trying to call examplesite.com&pageNo=x multiple times but currently only returns the source code of the last link in the list multiple times. I was expecting results to return the source code of every page in pagelinks list.

Both thingies return the same result.

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
    results = pool.map(load_page, pagelinks)
    for result in results:
        print(result)
        pages.append(result)
```

```
for result in executor.map(load_page, pagelinks):
    print(result)
```

This is the longer version of the code

```
def load_page(link):
    browser.get(link)
    #wait for necessary elements to load
    delay = 30 
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "sort")))
    source_code = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    return source_code

pagelinks = []
    pages = []

for i in range(pagecount):
        pagelinks.append(url+"&pageNo="+str(i+1))

 pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
    results = pool.map(load_page, pagelinks)
    for result in results:
        print(result)
        pages.append(result)

for page in pages:
    do stuff with page source code
```

For example, `pagelinks` has 5 links. example.com&pageNo=1-5

the source code of example.com&pageNo=5 will get appended to `pages` 5 times instead of every link's source code getting appended once.

Comment: Have you verified that the URLs received by `load_page` are what you expect (e.g., by adding a `print` statement)?

Comment: ...and If they are, have you confirmed that fetching those URLs in a browser returns the expected content?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed both of those things. Loading the pages invidually works as expected, of course slower though.